# BeautifulSoup find_all(text=True) not printing anything?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

All I'm trying to do is get the text from all the < td > but it doesn't return anything.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for page_no in range(1, 3):
    data = {
        'filterToken': "",
        'instrumentType': "EQUITY",
        'maxResultsPerPage': 10,
        'pageNumber': page_no
    }
    page = requests.post('https://www.nyse.com/api/quotes/filter', data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    print('PAGE', page_no)
    

    for name in soup.findAll('td'):
        print(''.join(name.findAll(text=True)))
```

I don't get any errors it only prints the Page numbers. I know there's already several find_all questions but none of them seem to change the result, perhaps my 'requests' is wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried printing the page to see what it looks like ?  Or ensuring there is at least one 'td' by doing `'<td' in page` ?

Comment: Check your soup -> `HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type -- The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource` and fix your payload issue.

Comment: @HedgeHog Ok that's gotta be it I'm looking into it, will reply back with solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so since it was a payload issue I decided to go on postman get it to work there and take the snippet from the code generator.

This is the code I got from postman (except for the for loop I added to change pages)

I kept the soup the exact same. It was definitely an issue with payload formatting.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.nyse.com/api/quotes/filter"

for page_no in range(1,3):    
    payload="{\r\n\"filterToken\": \"\",\r\n\"instrumentType\": \"EQUITY\",\r\n\"maxResultsPerPage\": 10,\r\n\"pageNumber\": 2,\r\n\"sortColumn\": \"NORMALIZED_TICKER\",\r\n\"sortOrder\": \"ASC\"\r\n}"
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cookie': '__cfduid=d1d98afcb22d3de94fabd5aa239a7f9dd1613587281; ICE=!JZg6hDNDz8MeToWQmW/NR4Un8KL87Pjjm4sZeq90MTiHJNFVEjMb6jE17JMo4Kqh30d5/r5S1JWaRw==; TS01ebd031=0100e6d4952c533b3a410d9219c173dd7215532f3c5eb2aa18ab3c24ed0e7523be4ae96305fe495c8f3ced04071d353afb732ef83a06090cec6f6dc7d40a1c2c7dcb86a73e'
    }   

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    print(response.text)
    print('PAGE:', page_no)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

    for symbol in soup.findAll('td'):
        print(''.join(symbol.findAll(text=True)))
```